# Setting vim background mode depeding on time of day

Tags: vim

Several colorschemes in Vim have two modes, which change the colors when you do:

```
set bg=light/dark
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to setup my `.vimrc` file such that it sets the appropriate mode depending on system time, for example setting the dark mode between 20:00 and 07:00 and light mode otherwise.

How could that be achieved?

Comment: Check this out:
[Conditional colorschemes in vimrc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368748/conditional-colorscheme-in-vimrc) Just check against timestamp :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24672/32419) is a beautiful solution from [Vi and Vim Beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), part of which I'm quoting below, that automatically changes the background for *all running and new* Vim instances depending on the time:

> You can use
> [`timer_start()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#timer_start%28%29)
> to set "timers" to run a function every *n* milliseconds. For example:
>
> ```
> fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
>   let &background = (strftime('%H') < 12 ? 'light' : 'dark')
> endfun
> call timer_start(1000 * 60, function('s:set_bg'), {'repeat': -1})
> call s:set_bg(0)  " Run on startup
> ```
>
> This will run `s:set_bg()` every 1 minute (60,000 milliseconds), and
> by setting `repeat` to `-1` it will run indefinitely (rather than just
> once).
>
> As far as I've been able to see in my (short) testing, this doesn't
> cause any side-effects such as slow-downs or flickering. You can
> consider changing the logic to set `background` only if it differs
> from the current value if it does (but looks like Vim is smart enough
> on its own).

For your specific case, you can add the following in your `.vimrc` to use light background between 07:00 and 20:00 and dark otherwise:

```bsh
fun! s:set_bg(timer_id)
    let &background = (strftime('%H') >= 07 && strftime('%H') < 20 ? 'light' : 'dark')
endfun
call timer_start(1000 * 60, function('s:set_bg'), {'repeat': -1})
call s:set_bg(0)  " Run on startup
```